# Manual approval step in a jenkins DSL configured build pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I want a build pipeline to stop after a job and wait for manual click until the pipeline continues, via the DSL.

I want to avoid the promotions plug-in due to the spotty/no support via the DSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [buildPipelineTrigger](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-publishers-buildPipelineTrigger) DSL method to add a manual trigger, which is provided by the [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin).

```
job('example-1') {
    publishers {
        buildPipelineTrigger('deploy-cluster-1, deploy-cluster-2')
    }
}
```

Comment: I had just figured it out myself, you beat me to it, thanks man.